# Magento Tax Prices Display

Tags: magento

Currently my site displays product prices both including and excluding VAT (tax). i.e. exc Vat £100, inc Vat £120.

I find on non taxable products, it is a bit unnecessary to have, exc VAT £100, inc VAT £100, displayed, so my question is. How do I configure my store to display just one price if the non taxable and taxable prices are the same?

Thanks.

WL

Answer (score 1):

In admin->System->configuration->sales->tax/vat

Try changing each setting for

```
Display Full Tax Summary  :  NO
```

Comment: Cheers HJB, tried altering the settings and both prices still show. I have my display price settings set to 'Including and Excluding Tax', but I wonder if there is a way to amalgamate the prices and display just one if inc tax and exc tax are the same.